# Why aren't my FCM push notifications coming through? (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I've been trying to configure FCM push notifications in my app. I can successfully send test messages in the campaign composer in Console, but when I actually move ahead with the campaign and send something, nothing arrives. I'm tearing my hair out. I'll list what I've done below - any suggestions on what I could have missed would be welcome.

- Necessary code is in App Delegate (see below)
- Firebase Device Token is being generated
- push notifications have been added to Xcode project
- 'background fetch', 'remote notifications' and 'background processing' are enabled in Background Modes
- Swizzling is disabled in p-list
- tested on a real device
- tested with the app active and in the background
- checked and double-checked APNS key
- bundle IDs all seem to match
- Google info-lists double-checked
- Xcode is up to date, packages are resolved

Thoughts:

- the campaign graph shows 0 sends after it's sent
- I'm getting the following error upon launch: '[FirebaseMessaging][I-FCM002022] APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID '793792630663'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.'
  However, this is intermittent. I managed to get rid of it for a while, but notifications still didn't work. Now it has returned, though.

CODE:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import WikipediaKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseFirestore
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseMessaging



@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {


var window: UIWindow?
override init() {
WikipediaNetworking.appAuthorEmailForAPI = "m"
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
 
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [
        .badge, .sound, .alert
    ]) { granted, _ in
        guard granted else { return }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("this is about to happen")
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
    
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self


    
    return true
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
  print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")
         
  let dataDict: [String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
  NotificationCenter.default.post(
    name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"),
    object: nil,
    userInfo: dataDict
  )
  // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
  // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
  
   Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .unknown)
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
 
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification) async -> UNNotificationPresentationOptions {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    return [[.alert, .sound]]
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse) async {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
}
```

Comment: did you add(upload) Apple PushKey(push certificate) to your firebase console

Comment: Did you ever find out how to fix this? I'm running into the exact same problem right now

Comment: @jari I did - not sure I recall exactly, but I think the problem was missing enabling the right APIs on google cloud. It's the bit with 'APIs and services' and if you go to 'Enabled APIs and services' and add the ones you need, think i just enabled any i might need like Cloud Messaging etc. and that worked. Another thing I did was allow swizzling, I think, thoug I don't know if that made any difference.